# Chrome dev tools service worker error icon/count

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, service-worker

I am doing some serviceworker dev stuff in Chrome, and I keep seeing this icon with a number - and it looks like a link.

[image]

Nothing happens when I click the icon or the number (4 in screenshot).

**What does it mean and I can get some more information out of it?**

I tried googling for "chrome dev tools serviceworker error count" and similar things, but was not able to find an answer - probably because the terms are fairly generic.

Comment: Once it is working, clicking the link has the same effect as going to the sources tab and the console tab for error. See answer below. Have you customised the dev tools tabs?

Comment: Hi. Did my answer below help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what happens in my setup

Latest Chrome 64bit on Windows Home

I created a hello world service worker web app from [service-worker-demo](https://github.com/jsnajdr/service-worker-demo)

- I installed http-server from node ( npm install http-server -g )
- I started the web server in the service-worker-demo folder ( http-server -p 2300 )
- I opened http://localhost:2300/index.html in Chrome
- I opened Dev Tools ( Chrome > More tools > Developer Tools > Application tab )
- I created some errors in my worker.js file (deleted bracket and semi-colon)

And the result is the same as what you see. Clicking on the number brings up the console lower tab with error and clicking on worker.js brings up the sources left tab with the code

[image: screen1]

[image: screen2]

Comment: Does bring up the console, but no errors !?

Comment: It does show the errors.